# False positive: Undefined or garbage value returned to caller

Tags: c++, xcode, arm, analyzer

The following code populates a result using inline assembly:

```
uint64_t Foo::f() {
    uint64_t result;

    asm volatile
    ("vldmia        %1, {q0-q1}     \n" // q0-1 = *this

     ⋮

     "vstmia        %0, {d0}        \n" // result = d0

     :: "r"(&result), "r"(this)
     : "q0", "q1");

    return result;
}
```

The `result` variable is unconditionally set in the assembly code, but Xcode's Analyzer seems to ignore this (the flow analysis skips straight from the declaration to the return statement) and complains:

```
…/BitBoard.cpp:26:9: Undefined or garbage value returned to caller
```

Is there a way to pacify Analyzer without wasting cycles initializing `result`?

**EDIT:** I've tried the suggestion to specify an output constraint:

```
: "=r"(&result) : "r"(this), "r"(&result)
```

But the compiler croaks with "Invalid lvalue in asm output". Removing the `&` compiles but returns seemingly random results. Changing `vstmia %0, {d0}` to `vmov %0, d0` also fails, with "Invalid operand for instruction".

I suspect that I have to mark `result` as an output, as suggested, and populate it differently in the assembly code, but I can't find any information on know to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the lack of an *output constraint*.

Try this,

```
uint64_t Foo::f() {
    uint64_t result;

    asm /* volatile */
    ("vldmia        %1, {q0-q1}     \n" // q0-1 = *this

     ⋮

     "vstmia        %0, {d0}        \n" // result = d0

     : "=w"(result): "r"(this) : "q0", "q1");

    return result;
}
```

You must use an *output* constraint, `"=w"(result)`, to tell the compiler that the assembler is setting a value.  You probably don't need the `volatile` if you do this.  At least, this is a good issue to eliminate.

Comment: This gives me "Invalid lvalue in asm output". Removing the `&` compiles and runs, but returns incorrect (seemingly random) results. Changing `vstmia %0, {d0}` to `vmov %0, d0` also fails to compile with "Invalid operand for instruction".

Comment: Try `"=Um"(&result)` then; the principle is that you didn't tell the compiler how it was set.  See: [ARM inline asm secrets](http://hardwarebug.org/2010/07/06/arm-inline-asm-secrets/) for some constraints.  These are *internal* for `gcc`, but I suspect that the same constraints work for *xcode/llvm*.  See: [constraints.md](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/constraints.md;hb=HEAD) for a full list.

Comment: That doesn't compile either (same error as `"=r"(&result)`) and if I remove the `&`, I can't get either `vstmia` or `vmov` to compile. Likewise for `Un`, `Us` and `Uq`.

Comment: I found it! `"=w"(result)`. I'll give you the tick since you set me on the right path.

Comment: `=w` is good as it is a standard/documented constraint.  I change the answer to wiki mode, feel free to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, though I'm still hoping for a more elegant solution:

```
    union {
        uint64_t result;
        struct { uint32_t a, b; };
    };

    asm
    ("vldmia        %2, {q0-q1}     \n" // q0-1 = *this

     ⋮

     "vmov        %0, s0        \n"
     "vmov        %1, s1        \n"

     : "=r"(a), "=r"(b) : "r"(this)
     : "q0", "q1");

    return result;
```