# ARM Neon assembler + C how can I pass and use array of pointers

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, neon

I have a C function and I want to load data from array of pointers passed to assembler part. How to do this?

```
float *pointerToBuffer

asm volatile (
   "vld1.32 {q0},[%[buf]] \n\t" 
   : [buf]"+r"(ponterToBuffer)
);
```

What if the variable was pointerToPointerToBuffer

Comment: What are you trying to do? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/195751

Comment: Does [this post help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119201/false-positive-undefined-or-garbage-value-returned-to-caller)?

Comment: `asm("vld1.32 {q0}, %0" : : "m"(pointerToBuffer) : "memory");` would to. If you want to pass an address / a memory location, use the `"m"(...)` constraint, and leave one level of brackets out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use one more pair of brackets if the grammar permits:

```
asm volatile (
   "vld1.32 {q0},[[%[buf]]] \n\t" 
   : [buf]"+r"(ponterToBuffer)
);
```

if not:

```
asm volatile (
   "ldr r1,[%[pointerToBuffer]] \n\t"
   "vld1.32 {q0},[r1] \n\t"
);
```